# Input type number value goes wrong in angular reactive forms

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a input field in angular reactive form of type number for storing price value, but when i fill it and console its value it gives me wrong value like for 899 it gives 898, 896-894 like this.
Please tell me why this is happening?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="mrp_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MRP Price <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-line" [ngClass]="{ 'error': (submitted || form.mrp_price.touched) && form.mrp_price.errors }">
        <input type="number" id="mrp_price" class="form-control" placeholder="MRP price" formControlName="mrp_price">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="(submitted || form.mrp_price.touched) && form.mrp_price.errors">
        <label *ngIf="form.mrp_price.errors.required" class="error">MRP Price is required!</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my **TS** Code part

```
 productForm = this.fb.group({
    brand: ['', Validators.required],
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    keywords: ['', Validators.required],
    mrp_price: [null, Validators.required],
    selling_price: [null, Validators.required],
    shipping_price: [null, Validators.required],
    stock: [null, Validators.required],
    sku: ['', Validators.required],
    short_description: ['', Validators.required],
    long_description: ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

Comment: What's happening on form submit?

Comment: Value changes like 896 becomes 894

Comment: i think "-" is not working on number change number to text or tel

Comment: I don't have any hypens and also i cannot change it to text because i am using type number on stock field too and stock number cannot be text type

Comment: Okay for me if i am use input type number and set value '12-12' it'll return null

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR Please check my answer and let me know does it worked for you or not? Best wishes :-)

Comment: I got my issue, it changes the value when i scroll down the page cause it is of number type.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this working Code:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="mrp_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MRP Price <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <div class="form-line">
            <input type="number" id="mrp_price" class="form-control" placeholder="MRP price" formControlName="mrp_price">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
   <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Register</button>
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" (click)="onReset()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        brand: ["", Validators.required],
        title: ["", Validators.required],
        keywords: ["", Validators.required],
        mrp_price: [null, Validators.required],
        selling_price: [null, Validators.required],
        shipping_price: [null, Validators.required],
        stock: [null, Validators.required],
        sku: ["", Validators.required],
        short_description: ["", Validators.required],
        long_description: ["", Validators.required]
      }
    );
  }


  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    // display form values on success
    alert(
      "SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n" + JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value, null, 4)
    );
  }

  onReset() {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.registerForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: Listen while adding the product it will work fine, but when i edit it then it goes wrong. And in backend my db stores in decimal format.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to bind and show data for `<input>` of `number` in reactive forms. Like on `ngSubmit`or using `(change)` event of that input. You can also check the value using `ngModelChange` event too. Here is my code and demo Stackblitz link given below=>

**HTML:**

```
<h1> Reactive Form Example </h1>

<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="form-line" >
        <input type="number" id="mrp_price" class="form-control" placeholder="MRP price" formControlName="mrp_price" (change)="onChange($event)" (ngModelChange)="ngModelDataShow($event)">
    </div>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Show value In Console">
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createContactForm();
  }
  onChange($event){
    console.log("On change value:"+$event.target.value);
  }
  ngModelDataShow($event){
    console.log("Ng Model On change value:"+$event);
  }
  createContactForm(){
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      mrp_price:[''] 
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
      console.log('Your form data : ', this.contactForm.value );
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Please check the [STACKBLITZ DEMO LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-va9vyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: are you check with "-" it will return null

Comment: I didn't get you @RaviAshara. Please correct where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Listen while adding the product it will work fine, but when i edit it then it goes wrong. And in backend my db stores in decimal format.